# Use cloudfront to redirect URL like a reverse proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront

I want to redirect an url and their subdomain `www.example.com/brands/*` to `api.example.com/static/brands/*` and `www.example.com/products/*` to `api.example.com/static/products/*` to avoid customers to have a weird URL.

I saw many documentation on reverse proxy using Cloudfront but I'm a bit confused about how I can setup it.

Is Cloudfront the best approach and If yes how can I do this redirection?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using the CloudFront itself without Lambda@Edge or CloudFront Functions. You can achieve this by creating a CloudFront distribution with the following settings.

#### Origin

- Origin domain: `api.example.com`
- Origin path: `/static`

#### Behaviours

0. Path pattern: `/brands/*`
1. Path pattern: `/products/*`
2. Path pattern: `Default (*)`

With this setup, when CloudFront receives a request say `www.example.com/brands/apple`, it will fetch the content from origin `api.example.com/static/brands/apple`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I tried this setup but when I hit `www.example.com/products/*` it redirect me to `api.example.com/static/products/*` .. as I asked hahaha
But I misexplained my issue indeed, my goal is to use only `www.example.com/products/*` without changing the URL in my client navigator but the current URL path where is the data is `api.example.com/static/brands/*`

So I guess I just have to do the inverse of what I did

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this setup:

[image]

[image]

But when I hit `xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/brands/random_brand` it redirected me to `api.example.com/static/brands/random_brand` instead of fetch data from `api.example.com/static/brands/random_brand` without display this URL

Comment: Same thing happened to me as well; did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Any update on this @ManasBajaj. I'm looking for the same.